# I'm How To Basic

Tags: symbols, alternate-reality-game

You should probably start by watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSXGagNzNLw).

At the very last seconds of the video (~13:28), a mysterious "code" appears briefly.
[image: ♋️♦️♍️♒️✍ video code screenshot]

Transcription: ♋️♦️♍️♒️✍

Obviously, I am wondering the meaning of these symbols, but I am curious to see if anyone discovers other hidden secrets throughout the video.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The symbols used are very familiar to anyone who's fooled around with Windows and Microsoft Word.
>
>  If you look at the *Wingdings* type face in Windows, you'll recognize those symbols.
>  [image]
>
>  Using the *Character Map* application, take the hexadecimal codes of each of those symbols to arrive at the following hex sequence: `2f 77 61 74 63 68 3f 76`
>
>  Convert those [hex codes to ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_groups) to arrive at: 
>  `/watch?v`
>
>  This is part of the string used in a YouTube video URL, which is followed by a unique alphanumeric identifier for the video. However, there doesn't appear to be any specific indication of what the identifier is, in this case.
>
>  *Note 1: I've chosen the symbol of a postbox with the flag down and its door open, since the pictured image in the question doesn't appear to have it's door closed (else it would be blue, and show a notch/handle).*
>
>  *Note 2: Upon a discussion in the comments with [**Christoph**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15985/christoph) and [**Carl Löndahl**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12901/carl-l%C3%B6ndahl), it has emerged that the first diamond (with square proportions) is the small one with a hex code of 77 (equivalent to the letter `w`), and not the large one with a hex code 75 (equivalent to `u`). I've updated the answer to reflect the same, the earlier (partly incorrect) answer can be viewed via the revision history (that earlier answer assumed the reference was to a YouTube user named [uatch](https://www.youtube.com/user/uatch)).*
>
>  *Note 3: [**Carl Löndahl**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12901/carl-l%C3%B6ndahl) has also pointed out via a comment that the sub-reddit titled [WhoIsHTB](https://www.reddit.com/r/WhoIsHTB/) is following this wider question of HTB.*

Comment: Wondering if the smaller diamond is the one to choose. The resulting string fits a bit better in my opinion, albeit the final url does lead nowhere. Maybe there's more in the video.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just `/watch?v`? If so, I would guess this is a hint to look for something which gives the rest of the link. Maybe it has not been released yet?

Comment: If you type in `/watch?v` here https://lingojam.com/WingdingsTranslator, you get the wingdings in the image.

Comment: Oh, there is even a subreddit for this https://www.reddit.com/r/WhoIsHTB/

Comment: @Christoph - my first thought was I had wrongly transcribed the diamond for the same reason you mentioned (/watch fits in better with YouTube), but when I tried out the "u" instead I found a user profile, which was surprising enough that I kept it in my answer. But you're right, the other diamond makes more sense, as Carl has also alluded to.

Comment: The reddit seems to have concluded that it means /watch?v

Comment: Thanks Christoph and Carl, I've updated the answer based on the information you've provided,